# Angular 5 Form validation and display error in generic component

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a generic component like below,

```
// selector: 'app-text-box'
<form>
   <input type="text" 
    [name]="data.name"
    [id]="data.name"/>
</form>
<error-message [message]="message"></error-message>
```

Also my app component like below,

```
<div *ngFor="let data of jsonData | async">

  <app-text-box [data]="data"
            *ngIf="data.type === 'TEXT'">
  </app-text-box>

</div>
```

And then my json

```
[
 {
    "type": "TEXT",
    "name": "book"
 },
 {
    "type": "TEXT",
    "name": "note"
 }
]
```

based on the above json, the app component will iterate it and render the input box, if I want to validate the both input field and then display error for corresponding input field. I don't know how to handle it using form?

Comment: I have added an answer describing the solution to your problem. Let me know if you need any clarification on that.

Comment: I'm getting 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addControl' of undefined' for this line 'this.myForm.addControl('someName', new FormControl(data.name, Validators.required))'

Comment: Sorry Add that code in your `ngOnInit()` not in `constructor`. I have just given you the design flow. Its not a complete code. You can definitely work it out

Comment: Working fine as expected, Thanks :)

Comment: Moreover how to validate server response failure using angular 5 form validation?

Comment: Why do you want to mix up server response error with form errors. They are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form object in your parent `app-component` say

`myForm : FormGroup`

```
constructor(private fb : FormBuilder) {
   this.myForm = this.fb.group({});
}
```

and then pass that as an input to child component.

So you have to declare `@Input() myForm : FormGroup` in child component

parent comp

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
     <app-text-box [data]="data" [myForm]="myForm"
            *ngIf="data.type === 'TEXT'">
     </app-text-box>
</form>   
{{myForm.valid}} -- prints true or false
```

An In your child component, add input controls to the same form group passed by parent

```
constructor(fb : FormBuilder) {
     // add input controls to the same form group
    this.myForm.addControl('someName', new FormControl(data.name, Validators.required))
}
```

child component

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm">
   <input type="text" 
    [formControlName]="someName"
    [id]="data.name"/>
</form>
<error-message [message]="message"></error-message>
```