# How to disable Parent Component Form Submit button if child component fields are not valid

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular6, angular4-forms, angular-validation

I am using Template Driven Form.

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<form #BasicForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onBasicDetailsSubmit()" id="BasicForm">

  <app-input-text [(sharedVar)]="dashboardDetails.Text1" [isMandatory]="true" ></app-input-text>
  <app-input-text [(sharedVar)]="dashboardDetails.Text2" [isMandatory]="false"></app-input-text>

  <input type="submit" value="Save" [disabled]="!BasicForm.valid" class="btn btn-success">

</form>
```

**Child Component**

**TS**

```
@Input() sharedVar: number;
@Input() isMandatory: boolean;

@Output() sharedVarChange = new EventEmitter();


change(newValue) {
  this.sharedVar = newValue;
  this.sharedVarChange.emit(newValue);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="sharedVar" (ngModelChange)="change($event)" [attr.required]="isMandatory">
```

The Submit button is not getting disabled. I have tried writing `required` in child component as well as parent component selector, but it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: In parent component html you aren't accessing sharedVarChange no?

Comment: No. I am trying it now

Comment: You could rather share the same `form` between parent and child. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281527/angular-5-form-validation-and-display-error-in-generic-component/51281984#51281984
Only difference is you have template driven forms. That should not be an issue. Once done, you can fetch form controls to validate in either of the components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `Template-Driven-Form`, the best way to validate `Child components` is to create a `custom-Directive`like this that you will always add in each field that you want to validate in the Child-Component-Form:

You can use this one:

```js
import {Directive, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgControl, NgForm, NgModel} from "@angular/forms";

/**
 * This attribute directive must be used to each input-field of a childComponent.
 * That input-field must contain a NgModel attribute, else the application must throw an error
 * Usage: (<input class="form-control" type="text" registerChildComponentToForm
 *          [(ngModel)]="testname" name="testname" required />
 */

@Directive({
    selector: '[registerChildComponentToForm]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})
export class RegisterTemplateFormModelDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor(private form: NgForm, private eltControl: NgControl) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.form && this.eltControl) {
            this.form.form.addControl(this.eltControl.name, this.eltControl.control);
        }
    }

}
```

Then register it into `declarations` and `exports` in your `App-Module`

```js
declarations: [
        RegisterTemplateFormModelDirective,
        ...
],
exports: [
        RegisterTemplateFormModelDirective,
        ...
]
```

Suppose that your `<app-input-text>` is this `HTML` code, then you should just use the `directive`(`registerChildComponentToForm`) like this:

```html
<input id="iban" name="iban" [(ngModel)]="bank.iban" #ibanRef="ngModel" 
  [required]="isMandatory" registerChildComponentToForm/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution is working great. Just 1 problem. I am getting the following error in console. can you please help with it?                                                               ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.

Comment: I have fixed it with `setTimeOut` , but I dont think its the right approach :     setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.form && this.eltControl) {
                this.form.form.addControl(this.eltControl.name, this.eltControl.control);
            }
        }, 1);

Comment: The approch with `setTimeOut ` is also correct. I use it too. Or use the approche with `ChangeDetectorRef` of Angular https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Answer (score 0):

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<app-input-text [(sharedVar)]="dashboardDetails.Text1" (sharedVarChange)="sharedVarChangeHandle($event)" ...
```

**Parent Component TS**

```
sharedVarChangeHandle($event) {
    // by evaluating the value passed you can update a variable (ex: disableSubmit)
}
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" [disabled]="!disableSubmit" class="bt .....
```

Answer (score 0):

**Child Component ts**

```
valid // this is a public variable

change(newValue) {
  this.sharedVar = newValue;
  this.sharedVarChange.emit(newValue);
  // here conditioanally update the **valid** variable (true or false)
}
```